# Multithreading in java cannot communicate change

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to change a Boolean variable in application thread(setReadyToUpload) and hearing this change(isReadyToUpload) another thread (server thread) will do something.Though server thread is in a while loop and checking all he time it is not catching the change when i change the Boolean variable in application thread.
Application thread

```
package server;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

import java.io.File;

public class serverController {
serverMain main;

@FXML
private Button upload;

@FXML
private ProgressIndicator indicator;

@FXML
void pressed(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fc=new FileChooser();

    File file=fc.showOpenDialog(main.getStage());


    if(file!=null) {
        main.setFileLoaction(file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("it is done");
        main.setReadyToUpload(true);

    }
    else
    {
        Alert alert=new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setHeaderText("Upload problem");
        alert.setContentText("You have'nt select any file to upload");
        alert.showAndWait();

    }


}
public void setMain(serverMain main) {
    this.main = main;
}
```

}

server thread

```
package tcpobject;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

import server.serverMain;
import util.NetworkUtil;

public class WriteThreadServer implements Runnable {

private Thread thr;
private NetworkUtil nc;
private  serverMain main;
private LargeFile o;
private  LargeFileInserter lfi;
String name;

public WriteThreadServer(NetworkUtil nc,String name, serverMain main) {
    this.nc = nc;
    this.name=name;
    this.thr = new Thread(this);
    this.main=main;
    thr.start();
}

public void run() {
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            //System.out.println("it is "+main.isReadyToUpload());
            // if i print this then thelower block works good but if i dont it cant catch the change
            System.out.println("it is checking");
            if(main.isReadyToUpload())
            {
                System.out.println("it is ru");
                FileDataHandler();
            }

            if(main.isStartUpload()) {
                //System.out.println("it is su");
                LargeFileHandler();
                System.out.println("it is su");
                for (int i = 0; lfi.hasMoreBytes(); i++) {
                    o = lfi.nextByte();
                    nc.write(o);
                }
                lfi.close();

            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println (e+"  here");
            e.printStackTrace();
            nc.closeConnection();
        }

    }

}
void FileDataHandler ()
{

    FileDataMessage fd=new FileDataMessage(main.getFileLoaction());
    nc.write(fd);
    main.setReadyToUpload(false);

}
void LargeFileHandler ()
{

    try {
        lfi=new LargeFileInserter(main.getFileLoaction());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //FileDataMessage fd=new FileDataMessage("F:\\L-2 T-1\\EEE 263\\Electronic devices and ckt theory- boylestad 11th edition.pdf");
    //System.out.println(fd);
    //System.out.println(fd.sizetoPrint());
    LargeFile o;
    main.setStartUpload(false);
}
```

}

All the function and variable is written in main class and both thread have access to that class.

Comment: Please can you specific your question?

Comment: Please give some more code

Comment: Can try with making your `flag`  volatile.

Comment: are setReadyToUpload and isReadyToUpload synchronized ?  You should provide code for these two methods.

Comment: 1) **never ever busy wait**. 2) **don't ever busy wait**. 3) for a variable to be read by two threads it needs to have a memory barrier - `volatile` will work in this case.

Comment: P.S. did I mention, **busy waiting is anathema**.

Comment: Actively waiting for a variable to change is usually a terrible idea. Maybe you should scratch that entirely and implement a producer consumer  thing [with `BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)(< example inside) so things coming out of the queue in your server thread are either data or events. Or use one of the many concurrency utilities that offer blocking semantics like a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), semaphores, locks & conditions, ..

Comment: I have to check many variable in that thread so i cant wait for a single variable(code added)

Comment: Thanks to every one **volatile** works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Without having the rest of the code available, methods `setReadyToUpload` and `isReadyToUpload` have issues with visibility of shared object, which is flag you are setting to true.

What could happen is that two threads run on different cores, and one thread updates the flag to true. This update could happen within CPU cache which is not readable by the another thread checking for the value as long the change is not flushed back into main memory.

You could fix current design by :

a) having the flag volatile which will force updates of cache lines between CPU registers

b) make methods synchronized, with the same effect as above

What you should do instead however, would be to use wait and notify instead of busy waiting in the server thread and wasting the CPU cycles.

Simply create `monitor` variable such as:

```
private final Object monitor = new Object();
```

and in the server code do:

```
synchronized(monitor) {

    monitor.wait():
}
```

so when the change is ready you could notify change from another thread like this:

```
synchronized(monitor)

{
   monitor.notify();
}
```

Server could implement `Observer` while your client is `Subject`. This would let you simply notify the changes via Observer's interface method `update`.

Note that in theory `wait` could be interrupted, and therefore you should check if the condition is met upon wake up, and if not continue waiting.

Comment: I have to check many variables in server thread so is it possible to wait for a single variable?(code added)

Comment: Take a look at the Observer pattern. I think it will help you better understand the problem, here is a simple implementation: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm . You should wait on event, not variable. In your case event is update of flag to true which could be turned into Observer's update.

Comment: @enigma your code exemplifies everything that is wrong with badly written multi-threaded code. In the age of many-core CPUs, blocking an **entire CPU** to test some variables is not quite as much of a fire-able offence as it used to be; but if I saw this in my codebase a `git blame` would be used and strong words would be had.  Consider learning about event driven programming or, at least, `wait` and `notify`,